# How to Calculate Cumulative Unique Reach Over a Date Range in PowerBI Without Auto-summing?

Tags: powerbi, facebook-marketing-api

I'm working with Facebook Ad reach data from the Facebook Marketing API and have a challenge representing the cumulative unique reach over a given date range in PowerBI.

Here's the challenge:

> On Jan 1, if only 1 person saw the ad, the reach is 1. On Jan 2, if a
> new person and the person from Jan 1 saw the ad again, the reach for
> Jan 2 is 2.

Therefore, for the date range Jan 1 to Jan 2, the total unique reach should be 2, not 3.
I'm aiming to represent this data on a PowerBI scorecard with a date filter. When someone selects the date range from Jan 1 to Jan 2, the card should show a reach of 2, preventing auto-summing to 3.

How can I set up PowerBI to respect this unique cumulative counting and prevent auto-summing for the selected date ranges?

Comment: So you need a running unique count of viewers over a range of dates? Is there a rule for when you can count a viewer again?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook/Meta should provide impressions and frequency as available metrics.

```
frequency = impressions/reach
```

So you can rearrange for

```
reach = impressions/frequency
```

Given the average frequency and total impressions for the period you should get a decent approximate answer. Unless you can pull the reach for the exact period this may have to suffice.